# Is it possible to invoke other mobile app from a code name one app

Tags: codenameone

I want to invoke google maps app by passing it location details from a code nameone mobile app. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Android here is the way to open any other app
[How to call one android application from another android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728465/how-to-call-one-android-application-from-another-android-application)

Now in codename one you can use native interface to make native call
http://www.codenameone.com/blog/native-interface.html

you can uses this CN1 native interface with iPhone as well but you have to write iOS code for that

You can invoke a 3rd party app from Codename One in all OS's using the [Display.execute(String)](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Display.html#execute-java.lang.String-) call, this is described [here](http://www.codenameone.com/blog/can-execute.html).

For maps there is a better approach though. You can use [Display.isOpenNativeNavigationAppSupported()](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Display.html#isOpenNativeNavigationAppSupported--) & [Display.openNativeNavigationApp(double latitude, double longitude)](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Display.html#openNativeNavigationApp-double-double-).

Comment: FYI added some additional ways to implement that

Comment: Thanks Akash & Shai for your help!